# SQL query inner join error

Tags: sql-server, inner-join

I am working on a SQL query please this one is showing this error

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

This is the query

```
select 
   *,
   (select top 1 * 
    from tbl_Renewal 
    where supid = b.S_id 
      and Payed = 1 
    order by 
      renewalid desc) as result 
from 
    tbl_SuperAdmin as b 
inner join 
    tbl_Renewal as c on b.S_id = c.supid
```

Please check and give me the solution

Any other solution for this actual task

please find the bellow task brief detail

table 1  `'tbl_SuperAdmin'` having on filed

data like example

```
s_id name age gtc.......
1     abc  23 .........
2     cda  42 ..........
```

another table 2 having `'tbl_Renewal'`

```
renewalid  renname date supid   Payed etc......
1          first   -     1        1    ........
2          first   -     2        1    ........
3          second -      1        0     ........
4          second -      1        1     ........
5          third-        1        1     ........
```

thanks 
pradeep

Answer (score 1):

You can't put a * in single column value,

query should be something like this

```
select 
       *,
       (select top 1 COLUMNNAME from tbl_Renewal where supid=b.S_id and Payed=1) as result 
from tbl_SuperAdmin as b inner join tbl_Renewal as c on b.S_id=c.supid
```

Comment: leave it this select top 1 COLUMNNAME from tbl_Renewal where supid=b.S_id and Payed=1 give the bellow solution if putting columname also duplicates are coming

Answer (score 0):

cut it short to below sql

```
 select top 1 a.*,b.*

 from tbl_Renewal a inner join tbl_SuperAdmin as b

 on b.S_id=c.supid where a.Payed=1 order by b.renewalid desc
```